# How to use a variable in a different context?

Tags: c#, global-variables

```
    private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Select Song";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filedialoglbl.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Path = fdlg.FileName;
        var pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Path)
        {
            Arguments = Path.GetFileName(Path),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path),
            FileName = "C:\\relax.exe",
            Verb = "OPEN"
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to select a file and use that file to run another program but I don't want to use windows default.

My error is in

```
var Path = fdlg.FileName;
```

The problem is fdlg isnt in the same context and i need to use the directory chosen from before, any ideas on how to do this?

From the answers I have tried this:

```
    private OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fdlg.Title = "Select Song";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filedialoglbl.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Path = fdlg.Text;
        var pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(Path)
        {
            Arguments = Path.GetFileName(Path),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path),
            FileName = "C:\\relax.exe",
            Verb = "OPEN"
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi);
    }
```

and I get an error saying 'OpenFileDialog' doesnt have a definition or extension method for 'Text' and with the line in the class:

```
private OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
```

I get a new error saying that 'GetFileName' and 'GetDirectoryName' don't have definitions or extension methods in the 'string'

EDIT

I renamed path to directory but same error

```
        private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var directory =filedialoglbl.Text;
        var pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(directory)
        {
            Arguments = directory.GetFileName(directory),
            UseShellExecute = true,
            WorkingDirectory = directory.GetDirectoryName(directory),
            FileName = "C:\\relax.exe",
            Verb = "OPEN"
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi);
    }
```

Comment: Simply store the filename in a member variable of your class.

Comment: You stick the path in a label so `var Path = filedialoglbl.Text;` ?

Comment: Alex K. I tried this before but the GetFileName and GetDirectoryName don't have definitions

Comment: ah, just rename the variable: `var fileName = fdlg.FileName;` to avoid confusion with the `Path` namespace.

Comment: Alex K. I dont think path is a namespace its a variable and im calling it in my arguements to be able to run the program with the file chosen from the previous class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the dialog in your runbtn_Click method only for the `FileName`. You saved it into a label called `filedialoglbl.Text`. Use it.

```
private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Select Song";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filedialoglbl.Text = fdlg.FileName;
    }
}

private void runbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = filedialoglbl.Text;
    var pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(path)
    {
        Arguments = Path.GetFileName(path),
        UseShellExecute = true,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
        FileName = "C:\\relax.exe",
        Verb = "OPEN"
    };
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pi);
}
```

**Edit**

You can't use Path with uppercase because your are shawoding the Path class and you can't use their methods.

Comment: Ive tried this but as said before,  i get an error because GetDirectoryName and GetFileName don't have definitions or extension methods

Comment: Alpha75 nope even with lower case still get that error ^

Comment: And change the Path to path when you pass them as parameter.

Comment: You have to use Path with uppercase ONLY to call GetFileName and GetDirectoryName methods.

Comment: Alpha75 'Path' doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: Yes. Maybe it would be better to use other name than path in your variable to avoid confusion.

Comment: ok ill use dir `            var dir = filedialoglbl.Text; // changed variable to dir for directory
            var pi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(dir) // dir
            {
                Arguments = dir.GetFileName(dir), // dir
                UseShellExecute = true,
                WorkingDirectory = dir.GetDirectoryName(dir), // dir
                FileName = "C:\\relax.exe",
                Verb = "OPEN"
            };`

Comment: Then you have to add the using: using System.IO;

Answer (score 1):

Declare `OpenFileDialog fdlg` *outside* of your methods as a class member (field), e.g.

```
private OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
```

Comment: rory.ap when i do this i get an error because GetDirectoryName and GetFileName don't have definitions or extension methods

Comment: That has nothing to do with my answer.